# Http-status-code 401 Errors not logged in Apache error logs

Tags: php, apache2, http-status-codes

I am setting up Fail2ban on our server. The apache.auth jail fails as unauthorized requests are not being logged in Apache logs. I have changed the log levels, set separate access and error logs for SSL, but to no avail. Only Http 403 are getting logged in error logs. what should I do so that I can see more error details like 401 in logs.

Tried changing the log levels and 
configured separate log files for ssl and normal apache logs

default-ssl in Sites- (Enabled, Available)

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel error

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    #Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    #<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    #       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    #       AllowOverride None
    #       Order deny,allow
    #       Deny from all
    #       Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    #</Directory>
```

When I try to reach a forbidden page. Other than this, no errors logged in error log.

```
[Thu Sep 12 15:00:53.276750 2019] [core:crit] [pid 50926] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.16.0.44:57549] AH00529: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/' is executable
[Thu Sep 12 15:02:17.713433 2019] [core:crit] [pid 50924] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.16.0.44:57569] AH00529: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/' is executable
```

Comment: Are you sure that your .htaccess has the correct permission for Apache's user to read? Seems it says there is a permission issue reading the file.

Comment: that is just a sample error in test case. i try a url that is forbidden, to check if it appears in error logs. 

Similarly i am testing with false credentials to see an error in error logs, but to no avail.

in other words, the error logs are just showing above mentioned error.

Comment: How you trigger your 403 forbidden error?

Comment: by writing test at the end of URL. which is only accessible to certain team members.

Comment: Are you using mod_auth to limit accessibility of the URL?

Comment: unfortunately i dont know about it. as previously said, i am very new to apache php.

Comment: If your 401 error response is generated by your PHP script, there will be no server log (unless your program it with the [error_log](https://secure.php.net/error_log) function to manually log it).

Comment: can you guide where can i find these configurations in php script?

Comment: [error_log](https://secure.php.net/error_log) is a function you use in your code. You need to find the part of code where you return a 401 response and log them.